# Does nginx consume resources when running non-visited websites?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, ubuntu-12.04

Do nginx's sites consume resources when they are not accessed? I have a *very weak* VPS and would like to (apart from my portfolio) host a few development versions of websites I am working on (running Ruby on Rails).

My question is simple: Can I do that? Say I'll have ~10 RoR websites running via nginx and passenger, each with about 2-5 visits per day. Is a *very weak* VPS enough for that?

Just to clarify, *very weak* means 15 GB HDD, 512 MB RAM, 1 proc. running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: This is an interesting question... but it's not really programming-related - more software/devops related. Thus it's likely to be a better fit on the sister site: ServerFault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no it doesn't.

Long answer:

- Nginx consumes a few kilobytes per virtual host in order to store their configuration in memory. Even with a weak VPS, this is as good as nothing.
- By default, Phusion Passenger starts your apps when they're first accessed, and shuts them down when they're not used for a while, subject to the constraints imposed by passenger_min_instances. Furthermore, Phusion Passenger ensures that no more than passenger_max_pool_size processes exist, so if you access 3 apps then Phusion Passenger will shutdown the first one so that it can spawn the third one. This keeps your memory usage in check, at the cost of performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can and you must. :) nginx save much resources of you VPS. Use it for statics and as reverse proxy and you be pleased.

P.S. You have ok VPS. It can be used for ~500-800 hits per minute.